# Running BibTex from TextMate

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to run bibtex from TextMate, but it doesn't seem to be working.

After I run `pdflatex` from Textmate, I click "Run BibTeX" to which I get the following

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (Web2C 7.5.7)

The style file: plain.bst

Found 0 errors, and 0 warnings in 0 runs

bibtex exited with status 2
```

After running latex several times, all that shows up in the PDF is "References" with nothing below it.

I'm using latex version `pdfTeXk, Version 3.1415926-1.40.9 (Web2C 7.5.7)` on mac osx 10.6

**Update 1** when i try to run bibtex from the command line i get this

```
$ bibtex ME265_Paper
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2010)
The top-level auxiliary file: ME265_Paper.aux
The style file: plain.bst
I couldn't open database file ME265_Paper.bib
---line 31 of file ME265_Paper.aux
 : \bibdata{ME265_Paper
 :                     }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file ME265_Paper.aux
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: try this: http://www.kieranhealy.org/blog/archives/2010/01/09/biblatex-and-the-textmate-latex-bundle/

Comment: @gerry, tried that, but either i'm not following the article correctly or it's not working.

Comment: What happens if you clean the folder of its aux, bst, etc, run pdflatex and then bibtex (and then pdflatex twice) from the command line?

Comment: @philosodad, see update 2

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Anyone got a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben's answer is almost but not quite correct. The problem that you are having is that bibtex is looking for a file that isn't there. There are two solutions: first, you can change the name of your .bib file to match the name of the .tex file. Second, you can put in the name of your .bib file (absolute or relative path) in the .tex file where you want the bibliography to appear.

\bibliography{bibname.tex} is what will help you with that. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

These errors arise when you mistakenly name the .bib and .tex files differently. For example ME256_Paper.tex and ME265_Paper.bib.

Comment: That isn't a mistake, actually. I almost never use the same name for my .bib and .tex files. But when you do use different names, you have to put in the command \bibliography{bibname.bib} at the end of your document.